# Black status bar on the iPad Pro with rounded corners

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcode10, ios12

My app always runs in compatibility mode on the new iPad Pro Simulator. I've installed the latest Xcode 10.1. I've verified it is linked against the latest iOS 12.1. When I run it on an iPhone XS, it correctly uses Safe area insets. Yet it shows a black status bar and a black stripe at the bottom where the Home indicator is located.

Even when I create a sample app with Xcode 10.1 and run it on the iPad Pro Simulator, it is launched in compatibility mode:

[image: Sampe app in compatibility mode on iPad Pro]

How to make the app use the whole screen?

Comment: @matt - you tell me. It's a plain vanilla Single View app with the background color set to green.

Comment: Can you post a sample project? I still can't reproduce the issue on the 11-inch or the 12-inch 3rd gen simulator. Have you restarted the computer? Cleaned out derived data? Deleted all simulators and recreated them? Those are all things I always do whenever there's an Xcode upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was seeing the same issue simply by creating a fresh iOS app using the Single View app or the Master-Detail app templates.

I got it working as expected by doing the following:

I deleted all versions of Xcode installed on my computer. I went to my `~/Library/Developer/Xcode` folder and I deleted the following:

- All files named `DeveloperPortal*`
- The `DerivedData` folder
- The `Installs` folder (which just had some empty folders in it)
- Under `UserData/IB Support` I deleted the `Simulator Devices` folder

Then I did a fresh download and install of Xcode 10.1 from the App Store.

After that, a clean build of the test app worked as expected. I don't know which of the above steps was really needed but I got it working.

Comment: Delete Xcode and install it again + delete DerivedData fixed the problem for me. Somehow the old installation of Xcode 10.1 kept on linking the projects with iOS 12.0 and that was the problem.

Comment: As the answer indicated, simply upgrading to Xcode10.1 and removing ** DerivedData** did not work for me. I happened to have access to another laptop with brand new Mojave & Xcode10.1 installed, then it just worked.

Comment: @WeiWANG I'm not sure I understand the point of your comment here. My answer does not simply say to upgrade to 10.1 and remove DerivedData. No one ever said that would solve the problem. And of course a fresh install of macOS and Xcode 10.1 works. My answers explains how I was able to get it working when starting from an existing installation of macOS and Xcode 10.0. I required several steps of cleanup, then installing Xcode 10.1.

Comment: @rmaddy You did misunderstood... :-) my bad though. I just wanted to back up your answer that simply upgrading will not work.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above answer and it did not fix my problem. I did fix my problem by setting a .storyboard file as my Launch Screen File in Project->Target->General. Previously, I had been using Launch Images for my splash screen.

This is mentioned in the "Optimizing Your UI" section here: https://developer.apple.com/ipad/

Comment: Based on the screenshots in the question, the OP is already using a Launch screen storyboard so my answer didn't address that. Without that storyboard, the black bars are much bigger.